# Why does Ubuntu use Debian "unstable"? How does it manage to be stable then?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

Shouldn't Ubuntu use Debian "stable" for stability? How does it manage to stay stable by using Debian "unstable" ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between stable and unstable? Guess what Canonical does what Debian does too to make it stable ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The terms 'stable' and 'unstable' are relative.  Debian is more stable than Ubuntu, but that doesn't make Ubuntu unstable.

In order to be extremely stable, Debian doesn't use the latest versions of software packages, but instead uses the more mature versions which have stood the test of time.  If there any security bugs, Debian will patch them, but they will not add any new functionality to the package until the next release of Debian.

Ubuntu, on the other hand, will use the 'unstable' branch in order to provide more functionality.  The packages will have been tested before release (including Alpha and Beta releases) but there is the possibility that a few bugs may have sneaked through simply due to the fact that they've been tested less.

After time, which includes bug reporting and resolution from Ubuntu users, this 'unstable' branch of Debian becomes the 'stable' branch of the next release.  Debian developers will then create the next iteration of 'unstable' with newer packages (and possibly more bugs).  That branch will later become Ubuntu and much later, then next Debian 'stable'.  And so on...

This is similar to other distros.  RedHat is very stable, but the packages in that distro start their lives in Fedora which is roughly the equivalent of Ubuntu in this context.

If both Ubuntu and Fedora used the 'stable' packages then new packages wouldn't get the real world exposure they currently do and progress would be very slow.

Debian and RedHat are generally used on servers as they need to be online all the time and very reliable.  Ubuntu and Fedora are less suited to servers as they've had less real-world testing.  They're fine for desktops though and users using those contribute to the future reliablilty of Debian and RedHat.

You could consider LTS to be somewhere between the latest Ubuntu and Debian.  When Canonical release Ubuntu LTS they keep away from the latest and greatest packages and use the more stable versions.  The non-LTS releases take a little more risk when it comes to chosing packages.  This ensures that progress is still made, while a reliable Ubuntu is always available.

If you're concerned about stability - choose a LTS version (14.04).  On the other hand, if you're happy to take a chance on a crash or bug and are willing to contribute to the future of open source software, go for the latest (15.04).

Comment: +1 The [Debian Release Cycle](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases) gives an insight into Debian's lifecycle and how their Security Team supports releases.  See also [Debian Backports](http://backports.debian.org/)

Comment: So does that mean Ubuntu is not very stable? What about the LTS then?

Comment: This answer is rather misleading. Debian stable doesn't use more stable software versions — it's just a freeze of unstable (well, testing, but you don't explain the difference between the two anyway) at some point in time. While stable does accumulate bug fixes without new features (i.e. without new bugs), that's not what stable is primarily about — changing less often.

Answer (score 8):

“Stable” in the name of a distribution doesn't refer to how buggy the software in that distribution is. What it means is that the included software is frozen in time: a stable distribution has the same software versions throughout its lifetime, which is measured at least in months and usually in years.

Software in a stable distribution does tend to be slightly less buggy, because bug fixes are made while no new features are introduced. But this is a second-order effect.

Both Debian and Ubuntu build their releases from Debian unstable. They take the current set of packages from Debian unstable (more or less — they ensure that they have a consistent set, whereas Debian unstable can break e.g. when a new version of a library gets in and the software that relies on it hasn't been updated yet). They then gradually freeze the distribution: no more major upgrades, then no more upgrades except for bug fixes. People test the frozen distribution for a few weeks (Debian weeks can be very long, mind); typically they find some bugs and inconsistencies so fixes are made and a new testing cycle is made. After a few test cycles the distribution is declared ready to go.

Debian and Ubuntu have different timelines and different goals when they prepare a release, but the core process is the same.

Comment: Instead of calling it `Stable` and `Unstable`, it would be better to call it `Static` and `Latest` to avoid sparking fear among users like OP.